# Сервис "отдающий сайт" в то время как хостинг не доступен

Tags: хостинг, веб-сервер

Как то на хабре проскакивала давно (2011 год вродь) статья:

есть сервис, на который заливаешь свой сайт, настраиваешь конекты к БД и этот сервис полностью зеркалит к себе этот сайт в реальном времени... это делается для того, чтобы когда мой хостинг упал или с доменом проблемы сайт все таки был в онлайне.. изменения запрещены, но сайт доступен... и выдает его этот сервис....

вообще не могу отгуглить его или аналог, помню в названии участвовало слово code и возможно fire у него еще один фришный тариф был.

видел действие этого сервиса тут - http://censor.net.ua/ когда их сервер "лег", сайт был доступен и ничем не отличался , за исключением небольшого информационного окна вверху - ""вы видите копию сайта с сервиса....."

помогите вспомнить сервис или дайте ссылки на аналоги

Comment: http://cloudflare.com? Насколько знаю, он является антиддос-прокси и не предоставляет возможности отдавать контент при неработающем сайте.

Comment: Они ещё CDN предоставляют

Comment: вот и скриншот http://take.ms/Ek7j6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.cloudflare.com/ Оно? Отдаёт статику когда сайт не доступен.

**Обновление**

Собственно это и предоставляет их CDN. Там тоже будет такое окошко и кэшированная копия сайта. Но вам вероятней всего просто нужен второй хостинг и переключение на него если первый в дауне. Но опять же, не закешированую копию будет трудно достать так, как вместе с хостингом обычно ложится и БД. По этому я честно не могу придумать серебренной пули (хоть она возможно и есть).

Comment: точно, спасибо! Вот блин, еще раз перечитал описание, не вижу то, что он может держать копию сайта, только кеширование.... но на цензоре точно видел...  а вообще есть то что мне нужно в природе? А то хостер иногда в дауне... а у меня новостной сайт... это не допустимо

Comment: Собственно это и предоставляет их CDN. Там тоже будет такое окошко и кэшированная копия сайта. Но вам вероятней всего просто нужен второй хостинг и переключение на него если первый в дауне. Но опять же, не закешированую копию будет трудно достать так, как вместе с хостингом обычно ложится и БД. По этому я честно не могу придумать серебренной пули (хоть она возможно и есть).

Comment: @HolyMonkey так что мешает БД вынести на другой сервер?)

Comment: @Lifeact, да в пень такого хостера. Вы можете свой VPS вообще арендовать за пять баксов в месяц и делать там вообще что угодно. А те, кто не может обеспечить аптайм, пусть теряют клиентов.